# How do I re-render component when a variable changes in svelte-kit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I have an array `selectedWeek` in svelte-kit which gets updated when a user clicks a different week on a a calender. However I need to redraw the page, which isn't happening.

`$: selectedWeek` doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing a bit more code. But one surefire way to re-render a block when a variable is updated is to use the key block `{#key selectedWeek}<!-- things you want to re-render when selectedWeek changes -->{/key}`

Comment: what does `key` do?

Comment: doesn't do anything anyway

Comment: Here's a simple example https://svelte.dev/repl/679ddc8392ee449591e5133598f111ae?version=3.46.4 But adding more code for your example would be a much quicker way to get help. If you provide a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then surely someone will have a valid solution for your issue.

Comment: pls Show whole code...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Svelte's reactivity is triggered by assignments

```
selectedWeek = [...selectedWeek, theNewValue]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this simple line

```
selectedWeek = selectedWeek;
```

https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects

Comment: doesn't do anything.

Comment: It should. Maybe there's something else in your code. Could you share the component code?

Comment: Turns out I was using beforeUpdate. Don’t know why but removing that solved all the problems.

Answer (score 0):

$: isItemExists = (Items?.length > 0);